# Service ajax requests from within angular app from electron

Tags: angular, electron

I'm trying to take an existing web application written with angular and wrap it in electron. I've gotten electron to open the angular app, but instead of the application going out to a web service, I'd like for the electron wrapper to service ajax requests. Example, the angular app tries to fetch at "api/subscriptions", I'd like it to request from the electron side and then have electron serve data fetched from the local filesystem. Is there a way to do that, or am I going to need to make a custom angular service that is only included when building for the electron environment? I'd like to keep the angular app as environment non-specific as possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SiddAjmera - I've tried googling for about 8 hours with no dice. Was about to just make a conditionally compiled service like I suggested, but figured I'd ask to see if anyone had run into this, or if electron might have some sort of undocumented api for intercepting ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WebRequest](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request) and intercept any request and then return your custom response.

It also takes in a filter so you can only intercept say "/api/subscriptions" etc.

```
const {session} = require('electron')

session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest((details, callback) => {
    //Stopping original request

    //Fetch from some file etc.
    const response = fs.readFile .... //Or wherever

    //Make sure to call the callback with response
    callback({response})
})
```

Comment: Ty for the help. I'd read through this documentation, but I saw no mention of being able to return a response. I tried it just you showed above (although it's in typescript [here](https://gist.github.com/FatalCatharsis/fb263bc906a267cf84270917ca54c505)), and when I run the application and trigger the ajax, I get this from the chromium dev console: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I figure this is because electron went ahead and tried to contact localhost:80 instead of just responding with my payload. Was this maybe only with previous versions? I'm using electron 3.0.3

Comment: Is your server running on localhost? The error seems like you called `locahost/api/...` but probably no server is running to handle that

Comment: yeh, it's querying at `http://localhost/api/subscriptions`. I wanted to hijack those before they left electron. What should the url be to target electron?

Comment: actually, I may be approaching this wrong. Is it a more common strat to host a little express server in the electron app and just serve the data back that way?

Comment: Yes you can do that too. You'll have to check if it's an electron app and route the traffic there.